# Grails : how to save java.sql.Time type in sql database

Tags: sql-server, grails, grails-orm, datetime-format

I added in my table named config a new time type column that is generated by Grails a datetime type in my database.

This my domain class

```
import java.sql.Time
class Config {
      int nbr_delay
      Time max_duration
      static constraints = {
      }
}
```

In my GSP page

```
<g:field type="time" name="max_duration" value="${fieldValue(bean: configInstance, field: 'max_duration')}" />
```

Now when I try to change the value of max_duration and save it on the database, it display me this error `Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.sql.Time for property max_duration; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: "00:30"`

My Controller

```
configInstance.properties = params
configInstance.save(flush: true)
```

I searched how to parse or manipulate this data type but I have not found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, if you have a `duration` field, use `int` or `long` to save the minutes or milliseconds:

```
import java.sql.Time
class Config {

  long maxDuration

  void setMax_duration( Time time ){ maxDuration = time.time }

  Time getMax_duration(){ new Time( maxDuration ) }

  static transients = [ 'max_duration' ]
}
```

Then you can do in your GSP:

```
<g:formatDate format="HH:mm" date="${new Date( configInstance.maxDuration )}"/>
```